# Nullpointer when remove data from BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, adapter, expandablelistview, notifydatasetchanged

How to prevent the app from crash when my adapter is empty. I used notifyDataSetChanged() to update my list...but when it's empty, my app crash.
I tried to check if my map is null, but it's not working. Someone can help?

```
public Adapter_agenda (Context contexto, Map<String, ArrayList<Classes.Eventos>> map, ListView lista) {
    dados = map;
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.lista = lista;
    suporte = new Suporte();
    nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
    webserver = new Webserver();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Classes.Eventos>> entry : dados.entrySet()) {
        nomes.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    Collections.sort(nomes);
    db = new Consultas(contexto);
    db.createDatabase();
    db.open();
    participantes = db.Consulta_Participantes(4);
    db.close();
    ids = new int[participantes.size()];
    nome_participante = new String[participantes.size()];
    for (int a = 0; a < participantes.size(); a++) {
        Classes.Participantes temp = participantes.get(a);
        nome_participante[a] = temp.nome;
        ids[a] = temp.id_participante;
    }
}

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dados.get(nomes.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childPosition;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_listview, parent, false);
    }
    if (dados != null) {
        evento = dados.get(nomes.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
        TextView Evento = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.horario_palco);
        TextView Hora = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.horario_dia);
        CheckBox add_agenda = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.horario_add);
        TextView eu_vou = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.horario_euvou);
        eu_vou.setText("Cancelar");
        String temp_hora;
        db.open();
        String modulo = db.Nome_modulo(evento.palco);
        db.close();
        final int id_evento = evento.id_evento;
        final int agendado = evento.agendado;
        final int hora = evento.horario;
        check = false;
        add_agenda.setChecked(agendado == 0 ? false : true);
        String temp_evento = evento.evento;
        check = false;
        Evento.setText(temp_evento);
        Hora.setText(temp_hora);
        String temp = getGroup(groupPosition).toString();
        add_agenda.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (check) {
                    db.open();              
                    if(db.Add_agenda(id_evento, isChecked)) {
                        dados.clear();
                        dados = db.Carrega_Agenda();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(contexto, "Evento removido com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    db.close();
                }
            }
        });
        check = true;
    }
    return convertView;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dados.get(nomes.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return nomes.get(groupPosition);
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return nomes.size();
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_expansivel, parent, false);
    }
    TextView NomeCantor = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lista_epx_item_label);
    NomeCantor.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
    return convertView;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return true;
}
```

The error occurs when try to count the children.

```
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.rs21.hallel.objetos.Adapter_agenda.getChildrenCount(Adapter_agenda.java:150)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.refreshExpGroupMetadataList(ExpandableListConnector.java:568)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.access$000(ExpandableListConnector.java:50)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector$MyDataSetObserver.onChanged(ExpandableListConnector.java:862)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseExpandableListAdapter.java:56)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.rs21.hallel.objetos.Adapter_agenda$1.onCheckedChanged(Adapter_agenda.java:135)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:137)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:92)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:104)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-02 11:14:18.692: E/AndroidRuntime(17814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Attach crash logs with question

Comment: try to use if(map.size>0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dados.get(nomes.get(groupPosition)).size();
}
```

to

```
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(dados!=null && dados.size>0){
        return dados.get(nomes.get(groupPosition)).size();
     }else return 0;        
    }
```